# "Major", "Minor": Any words for gauging more importance or less?

Tags: comparatives, comparisons

I am writing a list of descriptions of how much or how little importance is attached to an issue under discussion or to a product feature under consideration. I would like to have three or four entries. We are describing either the magnitude of the impact upon a customer or the value to be perceived by the customer.

The words *major* and *minor* seem like a perfect fit for the middle values. But what words would be used for a higher level of importance and for a lower level?

My only candidate for a lesser value is *slight*. I considered *trivial*, but it has a dismissive connotation, a note of irrelevance, which is not appropriate to my list.

For a higher level of importance, my candidates are *prime*, *key*, and *chief*. *Prime* seems to fit, given the common phrase *of prime importance*. But I'm not sure about *prime*. We will have multiple items with the label *prime*, and I am not sure if *prime* should only be used with a singleton.

Are *prime*, *major*, *minor*, and *slight* the best set of items for a choice list for gauging importance or for describing magnitude of impact or value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The far ends might be described as *critical* and *minimal*.

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*] defines [*critical*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/critical) as

> Having a decisive or crucial importance in the success, failure, or existence of something

and [*minimal*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/minimal) as

> Of a minimum amount, quantity, or degree; negligible